# shorten directory path in terminal of visual studio code

Tags: cmd, terminal, window, visual-studio-code

i was watching a tutorial. In tutorial, instructor just executed command `PROMPT $$` in terminal of visual studio code and his operating system was Windows.

changed his directory path to $$. Its not working on my machine. 
i have tried https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterPROMPTForCMDEXEOrCoolPromptEnvironmentVariablesAndANiceTransparentMultiprompt.aspx but its not working.

Comment: yea, I too tried. its not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found answer but it is a little bit different because the path 'C:\Windows>' didn't changed to '$$>' but it changed to 'C>' for all directories in drive C, and 'D>' for all directories in drive D.

**Solution:**
1. Go to Control Panel > System and Security > System 
2. In left tab click Advanced system settings.
3. Dialog will appear. Click Environment Variables.
4. Under 'User variables for "Your username"' section, click 'New' Button.
5. Use following in the fields.
   Variable name: PROMPT
   Variable value: $n$g$s
Click OK

if does't work restart your machine. working for me.

[image]